# iPhone (iOS 12) Keyboard disappeared automatically when click on input tag when build app using Xcode 10.1

Tags: xcode, hybrid-mobile-app, iphone-x

I am developing a Hybrid Application using Cordova with MFP.

Recently we upgraded the Xcode version from **9.4.1** to **10.1** after that facing an issue is when key in on input tag then the keyboard is appearing from the bottom and suddenly disappeared but this is working normal below IOS 12 version even build app using Xcode 10.1.

I am using native keyboard instead of Cordova plugin keyboard and UIWebView.

After removing the **viewport-fit=cover** as mentioned in "https://github.com/apache/cordova-ios/issues/417#issuecomment-423326624" the keyboard is appearing from the bottom as normal but the keyboard is overlaid on the input tag so could not see what we are typing in the input.

And also tried with "https://github.com/apache/cordova-ios/issues/417#issuecomment-428705830" but not working.

We expecting the result is while key in on input the keyboard should appear from the bottom and need to be disappear once key in finished.

Comment: did you find any solution?